# Android browser launches when activity containing WebView is closed while loading

Tags: android-webview

I have an activity that has a webview control, when the requested url is loading and I close this activity by pressing the back button and go back to the previous activity, the link or the request response opens in the device default browser.
I called the stopLoading methon on WebView control before finishing the activity containing the WebView.
Any help on how to stop this opening of browser?